# Moq, how to match 2 arguments?

Tags: c#, moq

I am new to moq, need help to match 2 arguments.

here's the example I found from quickstart.

```
mock.Setup(foo => foo.DoSomething(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(true);
```

but my function Dosomething needs 2 paramters (string and AccountType), AccountType is enum type.

I tried,

```
mock.Setup(foo => foo.DoSomething(It.IsAny<string, AccountType>())).Returns(true);
```

I know this is wrong. Please help me out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add 2 parameters to your setup:

```
mock
  .Setup(foo => foo.DoSomething(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<AccountType>()))
  .Returns(true);
```